# How to check exception of a member variable of an object?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, outlook

Are there any ways to check the exception of a member variable of an object or not?

For example, I have a Recipient object, called rcp. AddressEntry is a member of this object. I want to check the exception of the member before using AddressEntry.

I want to code a method to check the member variable, but I have no ideas. Do not use try-catch

```
private voice GetEmail(Outlook.NameSpace otl, string email){ 
    //...
    Recipient rcp = otl.CreateRecipient(email);
    if (rcp != null && CheckException(rcp))
    {
      //do my code
    }
    //...
}

private bool CheckException(Recipient rcp)
{
    //if AddressEntry of rcp object does not threw exception, return true            

    return false;
}
```

Could you give me advises or suggestions about this!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Doing control flow based on exceptions is known an **anti-pattern**.

You need to develop your code in a way that it doesn't know if it's going to throw an exception, and if it does it, you need to catch these exceptions and recover your application or show an error to the user through the user interface to notify that the whole application is about to crash.

Exceptions are *exceptional cases* and you need to focus on *regular cases*.

I would argue that your code should look something like this:

```
try
{
  Recipient rcp = otl.CreateRecipient(email);

  if (rcp != null)
  {
  //do my code
  }
//...
}
catch(COMException e)
{
     // Show a message box, alert, whatever relevant to your users
}
```